# Javafx get the width and height (resolution) of a video loaded as Media

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a video player using JavaFX.  I am loading a video from the local filesystem into the JavaFX class Media.  Then I want to get the width and height so I can set the Scene's dimension to that size:

```
Media media = new Media(
    "file:/D:/Videos/Cosmos/Cosmos.A.Space.Time.Odyssey.S01E02.HDTV.x264.PROPER-LOL.mp4"
);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
root.getChildren().add( mediaView);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, media.getWidth(), media.getHeight());
```

Yet when I run this code media.getWidth() and media.getHeight() both return 0.  How can I get the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Media class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html):

> The media information is obtained asynchronously and so not necessarily available immediately after instantiation of the class. All information should however be available if the instance has been associated with a `MediaPlayer` and that player has transitioned to `MediaPlayer.Status.READY` status.

The size is available when the MediaPlayer is in the READY state.  The easiest approach is to set a handler, before playing the media, that will call `sizeToScene()` on your window:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> stage.sizeToScene());
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

// ...

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

Comment: I add the mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> stage.sizeToScene()); and nothing changed -_-.  Is it possible to wait for the MediaPlayer to be READY and then just run the media.getWidth() and media.getHeight() commands?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VGR I realized I just needed to wait for the mediaPlayer to be loaded:

```
            mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Add Pane to scene
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, media.getWidth(), media.getHeight());
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.show();  
                }
            });
```